# Evaluate the Limit as it approaches 1/2

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \frac12} \frac{2x^2-x}{|x-1/2|}$$

Hi,
I'm just wondering If I answered this right.

```
lim x-> 1/2^+= x(2x-1)/(x-1/2)
             = (2x-1)/-1/2
             =(2(1/2)-1)/-1/2
             =0
```

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1/2^+}&= \frac{x(2x-1)}{x-1/2}\\
             &= \frac{2x-1}{-1/2}\\
             &=\frac{2(1/2)-1}{-1/2}\\
             &=0
\end{align}$$

```
lim x-> 1/2^-= x(2x-1)/-x+1/2
             =2x-1/-1+1/2
             =2x/1/2
             =2
```

Therefore lim x-> 1/2 DNE

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: You are getting into difficulties by not using parentheses. The limit from the right is $1$, and from the left it is $-1$.

Comment: @Kahama Clearly in [the original revision of your post](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/954968/revisions) you have tried to get the equations aligned. But they were rendered as one line. You can use [preformated text](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) or some other things available in MarkDown. For math it is much better to use MathJax; see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

$(2x^2-x)/|x-1/2|=2x(x-1/2)/|x-1/2|=2xsgn( x - 1/2) $as$ x\ne0.5$

Answer (score 1):

Since

$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}\frac{2x^2-x}{|x-\frac12|}=\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}\frac{2x^2-x}{x-\frac12}=\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}\frac{4x-1}{1}=1$.

$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}\frac{2x^2-x}{|x-\frac12|}=\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}\frac{2x^2-x}{-(x-\frac12)}=\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}\frac{4x-1}{-1}=-1$.

then this limit doesn't exist.